# Migrating data from Tiger to Lion

Tags: macos, migration

What is the easiest way to migrate data (software, documents, bookmarks, etc.) from an old Mac OS X (probably Tiger) to Lion? Time Machine with Migration Assistant?

Comment: Some Apps (written for PPC) will not work in Lion. Many other will probably have a different version for Lion. Thus it would make sence to backup your home folder by simply copying it to an external harddrive.

Comment: You might want to take a look at these two Apple.SE questions - they may work in your situation: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4025/how-can-i-transfer-data-from-a-g5-imac-to-an-i7-imac and http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5820/should-i-use-time-machine-to-migrate-from-one-mac-to-another